# listen for click event of google translator

Tags: jquery, google-translate

I added the free google translator to my site. I use jquery to add a fixed width to an element based on width of the header text.

if google translator is used. The page is not reloaded. So the width stays the original width.

Solution: I need to listen for the google translator and if its used then this jquery function is triggered.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Because jQuery and JavaScript are closely related (jQuery being the write less, do more version of JavaScript), you can assign an `event listener` using JavaScript and write what happens if the event is triggered in jQuery. I would personally assign the translator an id, get that element by it's id, and assign an `event listener` to it. [Some more information on event listeners](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents).

If you are only assigning one listener per element (and their `<div>` that they are located in does not have an event listener), then you can use this type of `event listener`:

```
var saveButton = document.getElementById('savebuttonId');
saveButton.addEventListener('click',myCustomFunction,true);
```

Or if you only need to use the function once, say to tell someone their progress was saved, and that's the only reason you need a function like that, you can do this:

```
var saveButton = document.getElementById('savebuttonId');
saveButton.addEventListener('click' function() {
  alert('Progress saved!');
}, true);
```

If the button is located in a `<div>` element that also has an event listener, you can specify the order it goes in. Just replace, `}, true);` with `}, ORDER, true);` If you do not do this, the functions could go in any order that they want, which usually varies on the browser the person is using.

Comment: I edited my post to explain the different kinds of listeners. Check them out!